Доступ к данным наследника хранимого в массиве типа базового класса
Я имею пару классов унаследованных от базового. Как хранить их в массиве/векторе так, чтобы при помещении в хранилище, индивидуальные данные унаследованного класса не срезались и я мог с ними в дальнейшем взаимодействовать?
#include <iostream>

// Базовый класс
class Script {
public:
    virtual void Start();
    virtual void Update();
};

// Наследуемые
class First : public Script {
public:
    int mass = 0;
};

class Second : public Script {
public:
    int width = 0;
    float height = 0.f;
};
//

void main(){
    std::vector<Script*> scripts;
    scripts.push_back(new First);
    scripts.push_back(new Second);
}


А они и не срезаются. dynamic_cast или static_cast.

@HolyBlackCat , то есть я могу использовать такого рода конструкцию для получения объекта?
template Type getScript() {
... поиск подходящего по типу объекта
return dynamic_cast(найденый объект);
}

Все типы фиксируются во время компиляции. Возвращаемый тип функции не может зависеть от того, что лежит в векторе.
